# fetch and print PDF file via an iframe produces white page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, printing

I have an issue with programmatically pdf file printing on Chrome. I need to run the printing via a user action with a URL as source.

I use the fetch method to get the data and then launch an impression via an iframe.

This produces an empty file ([result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raJxr.png)).

I found a codepen project that produces the same issue (not mine) https://codepen.io/Edo_M/pen/PjdKEd.

```
fetch('https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/flask-cors/latest/flask-cors.pdf').then(function (response) {
      return response.blob();
    }).then(function (myBlob) {
      var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
      document.querySelector('#pdf-frame').src = '';
      document.querySelector('#pdf-frame').src = objectURL;
      objectURL = URL.revokeObjectURL(myBlob);
    }).then(
      function () {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
          document.querySelector('#pdf-frame').contentWindow.print();
        }, 1000)
      });
```

Any ideas to solve the problem?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you ever resolved this issue? I get a white screen in Safari & Chrome, and also was able to reproduce using a more traditional XMLHttpRequest method:

Comment: I still haven't get a solution